# How to represent the point-wise devision in mathematical symbols?

Tags: real-analysis

For example, I want to represent the following Matlab script in formal mathematical symbols.

```
1./(1+exp(-X*beta))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\left\{X_{ij}\right\}_{nm} \rightarrow \forall i < n \quad \forall j < m
$$
$$
Z_{ij} = \frac{1}{1+e^{-\beta X_{ij}}}
$$